# Node gets deleted when author is set to blank in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am currently working on Drupal site using Joomlart template JD Fashion.I have inserted the articles using content type as story. I don't want to display name of author and publishing date and time for the articles.

For this I have simply edited the node,expanded the Authoring Information section near the bottom of the page, and changed the Author name to blank.

But when I save this configuration for the article promoted to front page which was made sticky at top it show's "Page not found" error and on frontpage "n/a" appears where first article was.

When I tried to undo changes the node does not appear in any category at all.It is also does not appear in published or unpublished status.

I am sure that I have just deleted author information.

What went wrong? Is their any way to resolved page not found error?

Please help me...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer for the question. For removing author and date information in Joomla art themes you have to go to admin->site building -> themes -> your theme -> configure -> configure -> here you will find "Display post information on" -> uncheck story or your content type.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do.  Do not delete the author but instead go here:

Structure->Content Types->Articles and click edit

From here at the bottom you will see "Display Settings"

Click this and uncheck "Display author and date information."

Comment: Thanks for replay I have used content type as story and it is not showing display setting at all.

Comment: You are not seeing the display settings?  A story is a group of articles and blogs right?  So if you want to set those I believe that would be shown in those particular content types instead.

Comment: your answer is applicable to basic core drupal theme but not for the theme I am using. I have found solution for it which I have posted here.